# Web farm Error in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-farm

Recently I am getting an error message when try to do anything on my website. It only happens randomly(no specific page).

Error is given below:

> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
>
> Validation of viewstat MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a web farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. Autogenerate cannot be used in a cluster."

I need your help in solving the problem.

Comment: in a **WebFarm**, you need to deploy your site in all Servers, and they need to be called exactly the same under IIS, just changing the server name. Did you do that?

Comment: you need to provide the exact error message coming from the application.

Comment: As the message is quite self-explaining, I assume you tried to manually set the machine keys as explained in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) ?

Answer (score 1):

As a quick-fix, just switch viewstate MAC validation off (web.config).

(in `<system.web>`)

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="false">
```

Comment: HI,

I have already implemented the above solution in web.config file. But still getting the error.

with regards,
Swaroop Kumar.P